# Wrong behaviour on formatting decimal

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, number-formatting

I want to implement TextField with formatted string (currency)

I use Binding to format entered String to Decimal and to show in TextField formatted string:

Problem: After 4th or very rarely 5th entered digit, string is skipping to 0.

Code from playground, which shows everything:

```
import Foundation

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "sk-SK")//locale
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.currencySymbol = ""

var formattedValue = formatter.string(for: 1) ?? .init("")
var number = formatter.number(from: "1")?.decimalValue ?? 0

formattedValue = formatter.string(for: 10) ?? .init("")
number = formatter.number(from: "10")?.decimalValue ?? 0

formattedValue = formatter.string(for: 100) ?? .init("")
number = formatter.number(from: "100")?.decimalValue ?? 0

formattedValue = formatter.string(for: 1000) ?? .init("")
number = formatter.number(from: "1 000")?.decimalValue ?? 0 // Problem here. "1 000" -> 0

number = formatter.number(from:newValue.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: ""))?.decimalValue ?? 0 // Works in Playground, but it doesn't help in real code (trying to localize this problem now)


formattedValue = formatter.string(for: 1) ?? .init("")
number = formatter.number(from: formattedValue!)?.decimalValue ?? 0

formattedValue = formatter.string(for: 10) ?? .init("")
number = formatter.number(from: formattedValue!)?.decimalValue ?? 0

formattedValue = formatter.string(for: 100) ?? .init("")
number = formatter.number(from: formattedValue!)?.decimalValue ?? 0

formattedValue = formatter.string(for: 1000) ?? .init("")
number = formatter.number(from: formattedValue!)?.decimalValue ?? 0 // But here despite of same looking formattedValue ("1 000") formatter convert string correct.
```

Comment: You may have more luck getting help if you post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you! I localized problem and added listing from Playground

Comment: "1 000" is not a string that will return a decimal value of 1000. That fails, and that part of the line returns nil. Since you gave the alternate default of 0, that is what you are getting. If you expect your strings to have spaces, you need to remove them first, before attempting to turn them into decimals. That being said, the answer provided gives you a nice clean way, though it needs some checks to make sure the string is actually a number before attempting the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would implement an extension, an update the text once the keyboard is closed. Might not be the best or "cleanest" answer... but I love using extensions on swiftui.

Note: Next time provide a code that can be reproducible.

```
extension String{
func format(string: String) -> String{
    guard let amount = Double(string) else{
        return string
    }
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale.current // Change this to another locale if you want to force a specific locale, otherwise this is redundant as the current locale is the default already
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    if let formattedTipAmount = formatter.string(from: amount as NSNumber) {
        return formattedTipAmount
    }
    return string
}}
```

Then use it like this in your TextField, if this is not exactly what you want, then just edit the extension to deliver the result you desired.

```
TextField("text",text: $amount, onEditingChanged: { (editingChanged) in
            if !editingChanged {
                print("Editing...")
                amount = "".format(string: amount)
            }
        })
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
```

Comment: Thank you! I localized problem and added listing from Playground